# WPF: How to group usercontrols into a collection

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, datacontext

I have a `Usercontrol` call `ChartBase`, and I have various axis `UserControls` that I can place on it. If I use it like this, all is fine:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Chart_1.ChartBase"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Chart_1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             x:Name="ThisControl"
             d:DesignHeight="700" d:DesignWidth="1050">

<Grid 
    x:Name="LayoutRoot" 
    DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ThisControl}"
    Height="{Binding ActualHeight}"
    Width="{Binding ActualWidth}">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="60*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <TextBlock x:Name="TitleTB" Grid.Row="0" Text="Title" TextAlignment="Center"  Margin="20"/>


    <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Uniform">

        <Canvas x:Name="ChartCanvas"                    
                Background="AliceBlue"
                Height="{Binding ActualHeight}"
                Width="{Binding ActualWidth}">

            <local:RuledTopAxis
                AxisBrush="Red"
                AxisThickness="2"
                Length="{Binding ElementName=ChartCanvas, Path=ActualWidth}"
                TickBrush="Purple"
                TickSize="10"
                TickThickness="3"
                TickInterval="50"
                ChartWidth="{Binding ElementName=ChartCanvas, Path=ActualWidth}"
                ChartHeight="{Binding ElementName=ChartCanvas, Path=ActualHeight}"/>


            <local:LeftAxis 
                AxisBrush="Green"
                AxisThickness="2"
                Length="{Binding ElementName=ChartCanvas, Path=ActualHeight}"
                TickBrush="Goldenrod"
                TickSize="20"
                TickThickness="3"
                TickInterval="30"
                ChartWidth="{Binding ElementName=ChartCanvas, Path=ActualWidth}"
                ChartHeight="{Binding ElementName=ChartCanvas, Path=ActualHeight}"/>

        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>

    <Grid x:Name="LegendSpace" Grid.Row ="2" Background="Transparent"  Margin="20" >
        <TextBlock Text="Legend space" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

What I would like to do, is replace that series of axes with a collection `AxisGroup`, so that ChartBase can really be a base class, and I can derive different classes from it with different sorts of axis collection. What I tried was to define a new `UserControl` called `AxisGroup` with just the following xaml

```
<ItemsControl 
    DataContext = ThisControl
    ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" />
```

where `Children` is a DP of AxisGroup which holds an `ObservableCollection. Then I can replace the sequence of axes in ChartBase by:

```
<local:AxisGroup>
    <AxisGroup.Children>
       <local:Axis_type1 
            ... 
            Length = "{Binding ElementName=ChartCanvas, Path=ActualWidth}"
            ... />
       <local:Axis_type2 ... />
    </AxisGroup.Children>
</local:AxisGroup>
```

Of course, the idea is not to define the axes in the xaml, but do define them in the code behind of various sub-classes; but this is just to test.
It sort of works. I do get two axes, but not where I want them to be, and not of the right length.

The problem seems to lie in the way the `Axis` base class works. What I do, for all axes, is set a horizontal LineGeometry, add some ticks pointing down and some labels below that. Then, in the class `BottomAxis` I set a `RenderTransform` to translate it to the bottom of the canvas. For a `LeftAxis`, I rotate, flip, translate to get it where I want it. That is all done in the base class, and the derived classes just set up some parameters of the transforms. That works in the first example, but it does not work with axes in the `AxisGroup`control. I suspect it is a DataContext issue, but cannot see my way through.

Sorry it was so long... Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

It is, of course, as simple as specifying the `ItemsPanel`:

```
<ItemsControl 
DataContext = ThisControl
ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <Canvas />
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```